# Add additional text pages in XSL FO (FOP) without header

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I can't solve one problem. I need to add a few more pages to the end of the document in XSL FO (in FOP), but without headers and footers.

I will print the invoice. I have one simple-page-master defined for the first page and another simple-page-master for all other pages. So far it's been trouble free.

However, I need to optionally print additional pages where there will be terms and conditions, a simple long text that will again be several pages, but I don't want any header on these pages and I need the text to start right at the top of those pages.

I have absolutely no idea how to create an additional (third) simple-page-master where I would not have any header defined, or rather I don't know how to call it just for the terms and conditions pages :(

I hope I wrote it clearly. Can someone help please? Thank you very much.

For example:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page" margin="1in">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="15mm"/>        
      <fo:region-before extent="10mm" region-name="xsl-region-before-first-page"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="other-pages" margin="1in">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="15mm"/>        
      <fo:region-before extent="10mm" region-name="xsl-region-before-other-pages"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>   
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="main-master">
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="first-page" page-position="first"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="other-pages"/>          
      </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>        
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="main-master">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before-first-page">
      <fo:block font-size="36pt" background-color="#ff0000">Header for the first page</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before-other-pages">
      <fo:block font-size="36pt" background-color="#0000ff">Header for other pages</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <!-- rows of document -->
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Row of document</fo:block>

      <!-- add some pages with texts -->
      <fo:block page-break-before="always" />
      <fo:block font-size="36pt">Some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text, some other text</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

And here is PDF:

[document-with-headers.pdf](https://nevicky.cz/tmp/document-with-headers.pdf)

All I need is, that on pages, where "Some other text, some
other text ..." is, will not be a header :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new `fo:page-sequence` for "Some other text, some other text ...".

Do not have any `fo:static-content` in the new `fo:page-sequence` so there's nothing that can be directed to the outer regions of the pages.

If you want different margins for those pages, create a new `fo:simple-page-master` (or new `fo:page-sequence-master` and the `fo:simple-page-master`s that it would use) and have the `master-reference` of the new `fo:page-sequence` refer to that.

The new `fo:simple-page-master`(s) that you create just need an `fo:region-body` with the correct margins.  There's no need for `fo:region-before`, etc., as there's no headers on those pages.